# Mongo $sum slow

Tags: php, performance, mongodb

I need I bit of light of how to use mongo to perform better. I have 2 projects using mongo, one of them has 140 millions of rows and every query runs near instantly, the data is displayed in little chunks so with a few indexes mongo is able to filter 99% of the data and return the selected ones quickly. Mongo work well on this kind of projects.

On the other hand I have another project that works like google analytics tracking visits, clicks etc. The objetive is to count clicks in a time range based on certain criteria (using a form). Im challenging mysql for the same task.

## First Try

I used the traditional schema of data, row by row, something like:

```
{
'user':'abc',
'date':'2015-07-20',
'hour':02,
[....]
'clicks':30
}
```

with 200+ millions rows (even with clicks pack by hour as you see), I have indexes by every field and some compound indexes by the most queried groups. Trying to agregate and $sum clicks by certain $match is really really slow if the resulted chunk of rows is big enough, even worse with that count of total rows, the indexes eat the 32gb of ram in the server.

## Second try

Using the schema advantages of mongo, designed a grouping schema to have the less duplicated data as possible, a schema where the properties of every type of click are determined by a unique combination of fields (with a unique index) and then clicks grouped on a tree distributed by dates, row example:

```
{
    "user" : "asd",
    [....]
    "date" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "years" : {
        "2015" : {
            "total" : 5,
            "months" : {
                "06" : {
                    "total" : 5,
                    "days" : {
                        "30" : {
                            "total" : 2,
                            "hours" : {
                                "16" : 1,
                                "22" : 1
                            }
                        },
                        "28" : {
                            "total" : 1,
                            "hours" : {
                                "6" : 1
                            }
                        },
                        "29" : {
                            "total" : 2,
                            "hours" : {
                                "14" : 1,
                                "20" : 1
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Thank to this strategy, the 200+ million of rows get reduced by a factor of 10 and the indexes fit in memory then, the inserction speed was slowed down because before inserting a new "row" you must check if one with the same characteristics is found and merge the clicks where it applies on the dates array if do exists before.

When I need to count rows, the speed have been inproved against the traditional schema, but I need to do obscure aggregate things like this to count data:

['$sum'=>'$date.years.'.$year.'.months.'.$month.'.days.'.$day.'.total']

This is performing a bit down the average speed of mysql in general, but the difference is so tight, even under certain conditions mysql win the battle by too much, considering mysql is counting 200million of rows and mongo 20millions, Its not acceptable because so many times mysql do a query in 16s while mongo resolves it in 120s. I want to beat mysql (myIsam) to use mongo as a replace. I have tried lots of things, from sparse indexes on the dates tree to a second level cache saving some pre-processed results and mixing them. Its not posible to cache all permutations of data by a certain day because the [...] fields are a lot.

Shards could be a solution but I dont think will magically improve the speed by 2.

Give me some hints, please

## Update

Lets search some days for a certain country:

### Mongo compressed schema

Mongodb count rows where country = 'AD': 11389

Aggregate:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [$match] => Array
            (
                [country] => AD
            )

    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [$group] => Array
            (
                [_id] => Array
                    (
                        [country] => $country
                    )

                [2015-07-01] => Array
                    (
                        [$sum] => $date.years.2015.months.07.days.01.total
                    )

                [2015-07-02] => Array
                    (
                        [$sum] => $date.years.2015.months.07.days.02.total
                    )

                [2015-07-03] => Array
                    (
                        [$sum] => $date.years.2015.months.07.days.03.total
                    )

                [2015-07-04] => Array
                    (
                        [$sum] => $date.years.2015.months.07.days.04.total
                    )

                [2015-07-05] => Array
                    (
                        [$sum] => $date.years.2015.months.07.days.05.total
                    )

                [2015-07-06] => Array
                    (
                        [$sum] => $date.years.2015.months.07.days.06.total
                    )

                [2015-07-07] => Array
                    (
                        [$sum] => $date.years.2015.months.07.days.07.total
                    )

                [2015-07-08] => Array
                    (
                        [$sum] => $date.years.2015.months.07.days.08.total
                    )

                [2015-07-09] => Array
                    (
                        [$sum] => $date.years.2015.months.07.days.09.total
                    )

                [2015-07-10] => Array
                    (
                        [$sum] => $date.years.2015.months.07.days.10.total
                    )

                [2015-07-11] => Array
                    (
                        [$sum] => $date.years.2015.months.07.days.11.total
                    )

                [2015-07-12] => Array
                    (
                        [$sum] => $date.years.2015.months.07.days.12.total
                    )

            )

    )

    [2] => Array
    (
        [$project] => Array
            (
                [_id] => $_id
                [dates] => Array
                    (
                        [2015-07-01] => $2015-07-01
                        [2015-07-02] => $2015-07-02
                        [2015-07-03] => $2015-07-03
                        [2015-07-04] => $2015-07-04
                        [2015-07-05] => $2015-07-05
                        [2015-07-06] => $2015-07-06
                        [2015-07-07] => $2015-07-07
                        [2015-07-08] => $2015-07-08
                        [2015-07-09] => $2015-07-09
                        [2015-07-10] => $2015-07-10
                        [2015-07-11] => $2015-07-11
                        [2015-07-12] => $2015-07-12
                    )

            )

    )

)
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [data] => Array
    (
        [AD] => Array
            (
                [_id] => Array
                    (
                        [country] => AD
                    )

                [dates] => Array
                    (
                        [2015-07-01] => 6080
                        [2015-07-02] => 6580
                        [2015-07-03] => 6178
                        [2015-07-04] => 6084
                        [2015-07-05] => 7085
                        [2015-07-06] => 7192
                        [2015-07-07] => 5672
                        [2015-07-08] => 6769
                        [2015-07-09] => 6370
                        [2015-07-10] => 6035
                        [2015-07-11] => 5513
                        [2015-07-12] => 6941
                    )

            )

    )

    [time] => 17.0764780045
)
```

### Mysql tradicional schema

Mysql count rows: 38515

Mysql query:

```
SELECT date,sum(clicks) as clicks FROM table WHERE  (  country = "AD" AND  ( date > 20150700 AND date < 20150712  )  ) GROUP BY country,date;
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [date] => 20150701
        [clicks] => 6080
    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [date] => 20150702
        [clicks] => 6580
    )

    [2] => Array
    (
        [date] => 20150703
        [clicks] => 6178
    )

    [3] => Array
    (
        [date] => 20150704
        [clicks] => 6084
    )

    [4] => Array
    (
        [date] => 20150705
        [clicks] => 7085
    )

    [5] => Array
    (
        [date] => 20150706
        [clicks] => 7192
    )

    [6] => Array
    (
        [date] => 20150707
        [clicks] => 5672
    )

    [7] => Array
    (
        [date] => 20150708
        [clicks] => 6769
    )

    [8] => Array
    (
        [date] => 20150709
        [clicks] => 6370
    )

    [9] => Array
    (
        [date] => 20150710
        [clicks] => 6035
    )

    [10] => Array
    (
        [date] => 20150711
        [clicks] => 5513
    )

)
time: 0.25689506530762
```

### Mongodb tradicional schema

Items count:

Aggregate:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [$match] => Array
            (
                [country] => AD
                [date] => Array
                    (
                        [$in] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 20150701
                                [1] => 20150702
                                [2] => 20150703
                                [3] => 20150704
                                [4] => 20150705
                                [5] => 20150706
                                [6] => 20150707
                                [7] => 20150708
                                [8] => 20150709
                                [9] => 20150710
                                [10] => 20150711
                                [11] => 20150712
                            )

                    )

            )

    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [$group] => Array
            (
                [_id] => Array
                    (
                        [country] => $country
                    )

                [count] => Array
                    (
                        [$sum] => $clicks
                    )

            )

    )

)
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [result] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [_id] => Array
                    (
                        [country] => AD
                    )

                [clicks] => 76499
            )

    )

    [ok] => 1
)
time: 27.8900089264
```

Comment: Sharding can give very big boost in speed. However question remains if you really want that/can allow that. From schema you can try 3rd approach. Create few more collections which have less [...] fields in them that way grouping data even more. If majority of queries use 2 fields, create one more collection with just those two and use big collection when more than those 2 are needed etc.

Comment: @Endijs Its a good idea actually, but its hard to find a most used group of fields because the queries are a mix of everything with no clear winner. The real question is, mysql seems more fast than mongo (not scalable, not as easy distributable, but faster for a simple scan), even if you use features of mongo that can improve speed over mysql, mysql continues winning :/ . Is there are some guidelines to addapt data to perform better in mongo?

Answer (score 1):

I was holding off on answer, because I was sure that some MongoDB experts will answer. However as no one is giving answers, I will give few hints. Maybe something of that can help. But then again - **I'm not a MongoDB expert. Take everything with small grain of salt.**

1) Which version are you using? If you are still on 2.6 - try out 3.0.x (or newer) with WiredTiger engine.
2) If you have a lot of data sharding can greatly help. This will increase setup complexity, but as you will be able to process parts of data set in paralell, you can get significant speed gains. But be careful with choosing proper sharding key.
3) Consider creation of several collections which can act as smaller views. Example: if you currently have 15 fields in [..] there is great chance that lots of queries just use 1 or 2 at once. Like country. Create one more collection in which you use country data and skip rest. If query uses only country fields and not other of those 15, then use small collection. If query uses more fields, use big one. That way queries on countries will be much faster as you will be able to group data more. However not always this is possible as it adds extra complexity in building such small collections. If you process data in some queue (to insert in big), you could insert in small too. Or you could use some aggregate queries and $out to build smaller tables once every X minutes.
4) Come up with 3rd schema. Yours 2nd schema is easy to put data in, but its hard to get data out. You could use arrays more. That way it will be harder to get data in, but much more easy and faster to query it. Keep in mind that in your 2nd schema and in my sample for 3rd schema documents are growing and there can be need for MongoDB to move them around on disk and that is really slow operation. Test if that affects your setup. Small example of potential collection schema:

```
{
    "user": "asd",
    [...],
    "date": ISODate("2015-07-01T00:00:00Z"), // first date of the month
    "total": 2222,
    "daily": [
        {"date": ISODate("2015-07-01T00:00:00Z"), "total": 22},
        {"date": ISODate("2015-07-11T00:00:00Z"), "total": 200},
        {"date": ISODate("2015-07-20T00:00:00Z"), "total": 2000},
   ]
}
```

When inserting data you can use update with criteria (if you are in PHP): `$criteria = ["user": "asd", "daily.date": new MongoDate("...."), // other fields]` and update clause `$update = ['$inc': ["total: 1, 'daily.$.total': 1]]` . Check how many rows were updated. If 0, then create insert from the same data. I.e. unset `$criteria['daily.date']` and change update to `$update = ['$inc' => ['total' => 1], '$push' => ['daily' => ['date' => new MonoDate('..'), 'total': 1]]]`. Keep in mind that you can run into problems if you have several scripts which insert data. Better do everything in queue by one. Or you do in parallel make sure that $push does not result in adding several daily.date with the same date. So - you try to update, if cant update, insert. As you use arrays and possitional operator, you can't use upserts. That's why there is extra insert needed. As I said, its more complicated to get data in. But it will be more easy to get data out. Make sure to set up proper indexes. For example on 'daily.date' etc. So that update queries would not need to check lots of documents. Even more - you can create some hash field to put [...] fields which would hold hash of all [...] fields. And use that in update. That way it will be much more easy to create small index to pinpoint particular document (you put in index 'daily.date', hash field and few more, but will not need to put 15 [..] fields). 
When you have such structure you could do a lot of things with queries. For example - if you need full months, just query on date and [...] fields that you need, sum total and you are good. If you need some date range (like 1st - 10th of the month) you can query by [...] fields and date, project to get rid of unnecessary fields, $unwind daily, match again, but this time on daily.date field, then project to rename fields, then group and sum. It's much more flexible than use of $date.years.2015.months.07.days.03.total .

Keep in mind that all of those are just hints. Test everything on your own. And maybe 1 o 5 hints will work. But that can make all the difference.

Comment: Thanks so much for the response.

1) Im using the very last version with WT activated and zlib on.
2) will test it then, but cant swallow mongo need 3 servers to do what mysql do with 1 :S

Comment: 3) The problem with this approach is that I will need to make lots of permutations of the involved fields, cause maybe this week the country+os is the most popular query, but its changes very quickly. I made the 2nd schema because it reduced count of rows and was versatile, been able to query every posible combination of rows and counting the result. Having table as little views as you said increase inserction time and add too much overhead from my pov. Again, mysql did it in only one main table and mongo will need multiple :S

Comment: What about 4) ? New schema that i suggested. It reduces document count like your 2nd schema, but is more easy to do queries on.

Comment: 4) This is very interesting in my opinion, maybe the bottle neck is when mongo has to count multiple level arrays (no idea how to measure it), the schema was interesting because you could count months and years on his own, optimizing the time, but with later analysis this is not as regular as I though, and even if it was, counting 360 elements/a year maybe its faster if the array is simpler. I though too making sparse hash indexes for every array day, but was not faster at all. You mention hashing fields, If you make this you lose the habitily to query certain fields to filter some data.

Comment: Hashed field is for quicker updates. As with hashed field + month you get pretty much unique key - i.e. - unique key to pinpoint [...]  combination in given month for given user. You would not use it to query data. For data query you would set up different indexes. Anyhow - i'm no MongoDB expert. But such ideas came in my mind while i was thinking about it. Maybe someone else have better ideas. If you find out something that works great - please share.

Comment: Thanks, and dont worry :-), Im in the same boat as you, Im a mongo fan, but never faced a similar case. Its not easy to work with 200+ millions rows, populate and testing consumes a lot of time. Almost I want to match mysql speed to get rid of it, with that I will be happy enough. From my experience, mongo is much faster selecting fields (find vs select) than mysql but much worse processing data ($sum).